# Laravel 4: How to add scope to DB::table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

With Eloquent models adding scopes is easy:

```
public function scopeMyScope($query)
{
   // Do stuff to that $query
}
```

But how to add scope to `DB::table`?

I use this query to get page views:

```
$views = DB::table('page_views')
    ->where('id', $this->id)
    ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%bot%')
    ->count(DB::raw('distinct session, DATE(created_at)'));
```

I also show the most popular pages etc with other queries, but with the same  `where` conditions. So I would like to only define my `where` conditions once and reuse them in all other page view `DB::table` queries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DB::table` doesn't have support for scopes. What you could do is simply write a little function that does some things with the query and returns it. The syntax isn't as nice but it works:

```
function applyScope($query){
    $query->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
    $query->where('foo', 'bar');
    return $query;
}
```

And then:

```
$query = DB::table('page_views')
    ->where('id', $this->id)
    ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%bot%');
$query = applyScope($query);
$views = $query->count(DB::raw('distinct session, DATE(created_at)'));
```

Or a bit a shorter syntax:

```
$views = applyScope( DB::table('page_views')
                       ->where('id', $this->id)
                       ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%bot%')
         )->count(DB::raw('distinct session, DATE(created_at)'));
```

Comment: Good tip, this gave me the idea of creating a `PageViewQueryBuilder` class that extends `DB` and has it's own `table` function: `$query = parent::table('page_views')->where('user', null)` etc, etc. Experimenting with it now.

Comment: Great! Let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: I implemented this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28429629/3903565). Thanks for giving me the idea :)

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to [lukasgeiter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28420807/3903565) I got the idea of creating a class for this, that extends `DB` and returns the beginning of a query that can be built upon:

```
class PageViewQueryBuilder extends DB {

    public static function table()
    {
        $query = parent::table('page_views')
            ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%bot%')
            ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%spider%')
            ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%crawler%')
            ;

        return $query;
    }
}
```

I can now use this to create a number of different queries, all with the same where conditions.

Get view count for a specific page:

```
$count = PageViewQueryBuilder::table()
    ->where('page_id', $id)
    ->count(DB::raw('distinct session, DATE(created_at)'));
```

Get all views for a specific page:

```
$views = PageViewQueryBuilder::table()
    ->where('page_id', $id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('session', DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
    ->get();
```

Get the 10 most popular pages for the last three months:

```
$views = PageViewQueryBuilder::table()
    ->selectRaw('page_id as page_id, count(distinct session, DATE(created_at)) as page_views')
    ->whereRaw('created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW()')
    ->groupBy('page_id')
    ->orderBy('page_views', 'desc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Been using lukas's solution works like a treat; I am calling the scope from the model where it has been defined it just avoids duplicating the function.

```
$query = DB::table('page_views')
    ->where('id', $this->id)
    ->where('agent', 'NOT LIKE', '%bot%');
$query = (new myModel())->scopeMyScope($query);
$views = $query->count(DB::raw('distinct session, DATE(created_at)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom class that passes all functions to the `DB` facade exept your custom queries. Like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utilities;

use DB;

class CustomDB
{
    private $db;

    private static $instance = null;

    private $exitCalls;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->exitCalls = ['get', 'find', 'pluck', 'first', 'value', 'chunk', 'chunkById', 'count', 'max', 'avg', 'exists', 'doesntExist'];
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $result = call_user_func_array([self::$instance->db, $name], $arguments);

        if (in_array($name, $this->exitCalls)) {
            return $result;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function table($string)
    {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new CustomDB();
        }

        self::$instance->db = DB::table($string);

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function myCustomQuery()
    {
         self::$instance->db->where('name','=','frank');
         return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call:

```
CustomDB::table('users')->myCustomQuery()->get();
```