# Laravel scope in join method doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, scope

This is my function:

```
public function getspecifications($id) {

    $specifications = DB::table('products')
        ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
        ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->join('subspecifications', function ($keys) {
            $keys->on('subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
            ->Status('Active');
        })
        ->groupBy('subspecifications.id')
        ->get();

    return response()->json($specifications);

}
```

it works if I remove `->Status('Active')` which is my scope,

`scope`

```
public function scopeStatus($query, $status)
{
      $statuses = Status::where('title', $status)->pluck('id'); // Or relevant column name
      return $query->whereIn('status_id', $statuses);
}
```

> any idea of how can i implement my scope in this query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420635/laravel-4-how-to-add-scope-to-dbtable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Wreigh `$views = applyScope( DB::table('page_views')` that would work if my scope was belong to my `products` table but my scope is belong to `subspecifications` table so i cannot cover my `products` table query with that.

Comment: does your code with the scope gives you error?

Comment: @Ikong as i returning my result with json, so no i don't get error in my blade but no result as well. just getting empty select field

Answer (score 0):

[`Scopes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes) should always chaining with query builder instance. The code you provided, `$key` is [`JoinClause`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) ([API](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html)) and should not chain with scope.

```
$specifications = DB::table('products')
    ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
    ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('subspecifications', function ($keys) {
        $keys->on('subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id');
    })
    ->status('Active') // chain with query builder
    ->groupBy('subspecifications.id')
    ->get();
```